# How to ask my optician check my eyes for glasses in proper english?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, expressions, spoken-english

How can I ask my optician for an eyes check for myself in proper English. I am thinking something along the line of

```
Can I have my eyes checked?
```

or

```
I would like to have an eyes check, please.
```

What would be a natural and grammatically correct way to ask?

English is not my primary language. So, I am not sure what is the most appropriate way to ask.

Comment: Why the down votes? Chris, please visit [ell.se] also, you may find it useful to you as an non-native speaker of English.

Comment: Please note that [*english*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/english) is the "spinning or rotary motion given to a ball around the vertical axis, as in billiards or bowling". The language is *English*, with a capital E. A completely different word.

Answer (score 1):

Your first phrase is correct. The second one is close, but you would say:

> I would like to have an eye check, please.

instead. You could also say:

> I'd like to have my eyes tested.
>   Can I have an eye test.

Note that even though you want both eyes checked, it is called an `eye check` or `eye test`.

> I'd like to get my prescription checked.

In this case, your "prescription" is the information that the test produces. Your prescription is used to find appropriate glasses for you.